# How can I show the data for only selected check box

Tags: angularjs, html, css

Here I want to show Name, Country values through `$http`, The data is showing in the table this is fine, but when I check any check box in that table I want to display Name, Country values of that selected checkbox. How can I do that?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });

  $scope.showDetails = function(indexVal, values) {
    var getDataValue = {};
    if (values) {
      alert($scope.myData.records.Name[indexVal]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <table style="width:100%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Index</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Country</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
        <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{x.Name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{x.Country}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="chkVal1" ng-model="chkVal" ng-change="showDetails($index, chkVal)" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%; float:left; padding-left:1%;">
    i want to show Name and Contry for selected Checkbox only
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you  aware that checkboxes let you select more than one item? That said, can you specify what's the expected behavior when there is an element checked already, and then another checkbox is checked?

Comment: I've rolled back to include @HereticMonkey's edit. Please do not roll back good edits here - this is regarded as vandalism.

Comment: I've rolled back to include @MarkSchultheiss's edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, it works:

(Code explained below).

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getDataValue = [];
  $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });

  $scope.showDetails = function(data) {
    
    if ($.inArray(data, $scope.getDataValue) === -1) {
      $scope.getDataValue.push(data);
    } else {
      var index = $scope.getDataValue.indexOf(data)
      $scope.getDataValue.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log($scope.getDataValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <table style="width:100%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Index</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Country</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
        <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{x.Name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{x.Country}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="chkVal1" ng-model="chkVal" ng-change="showDetails(x)" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%; float:left; padding-left:1%;">
    <b>Selected Name and Country</b>
    <div ng-repeat="x in getDataValue">
      {{x.Name}} - {{x.Country}}

    </div>
  </div>
```

### Explanation

Function `showDetails(x)` gets triggered on check/uncheck of the check box.
Parameter `x` is an object in the array you pressed at that instance.

Then, it checks whether the object (i.e, data) is present in the array (i.e, `$scope.getDataValue`) or not. `if ($.inArray(data, $scope.getDataValue) === -1)`

If it is absent, it just pushes the object in the array and shows the array.

Else, it deletes the object which is unchecked and shows the remaining array.

Comment: Answers which explain what code changed and why are usually upvoted more than answers which simply give code which works.

Comment: I would rather not to use jQuery for such a simple task as checking if a value is in an array.

Comment: `if($scope.getDataValue.indexOf(data)===-1)` if you don't prefer jQuery. Though jQuery script tag is present in his code.